# makefile variable assignment under a target

Tags: variables, makefile, eval

I was running the following commands in a target in my Makefile.

```
target1:
        <run some command which creates ids.log>
        $(eval id1 := $(shell cat ids.log | head -1))
        @echo id is $(id1)
        <some other command which uses the value $(id1)>
```

My task is to get the first line in "ids.log" and keep it in a variable id1, so that I can use the value in the command I will execute next in this target.

I get an error running this command "cat: ids.log: No such file or directory". Looks like $(eval .. ) command is executed at the beginning of make rather than as part of the target make. And since the ids.log is not created until the target make is done, we get this error.

Can anyone help in how to get the value of the shell command I execute and put it in a variable for use on demand?

Answer (score 5):

Have a separate target that makes `ids.log` first then have that as a dependency to `target`.

for example:

```
ids.log:
    echo 1 > ids.log

target: ids.log
    $(eval id1 := $(shell cat ids.log | head -1))
    @echo id is $(id1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Simon. It works. Is there a way we could do this without adding a dependency?

Comment: I guess replace wherever you use ``$(id1)`` in subsequent commands with ``cat ids.log | head -1`` in backticks but I think the solution I gave in the answer is cleaner.

Comment: @SimonGibbons Hi, thanks for this answer. I tried it but with     `echo $(shell whoami) > whoami.log`but didn't work. any idea how to get the value of a target from a command ?